# Using tsql, is it possible to tag/group duplicates with unique numbers?

Tags: t-sql

Finding duplicates in a table is fairly easy but I'm looking for a way to group those duplicates with unique identifiers. For example -

Table -

```
Id    Col1  Col2   Col3
1     A     A2     B3
2     B     A2     B3
3     C     A22    B33
4     D     A22    B33
```

The output should be -

```
Col2   Col3   UniqueId 
A2     B3     1
A22    B33    2
```

This SQL will be run over a million rows. I wonder if it's possible to do it without group by (unless group by is the most efficient way of doing it)

Comment: did my answer do the job for you?

Comment: Thank you. Seems to work well after adding the having count(*) > 1. I wonder if it is possible to do it without group by to improve performance? This SQL will be run over a million rows.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER()` something like this

Test Data

```
CREATE TABLE #TestData (ID int, Col1 varchar(1), Col2 varchar(3), Col3 varchar(3))
INSERT INTO #TestData (ID, Col1, Col2, Col3)
VALUES
 (1,'A','A2','B3')
,(2,'B','A2','B3')
,(3,'C','A22','B33')
,(4,'D','A22','B33')
```

Query

```
SELECT Col2, Col3, UniqueID FROM
    (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() 
        OVER (ORDER BY Col2, Col3) AS UniqueID, 
        Col2, Col3 
    FROM #TestData GROUP BY Col2, Col3) AS EMP
```

Result

```
Col2    Col3    UniqueID
A2      B3      1
A22     B33     2
```

Comment: Thank you. Seems to work well after adding the having count(*) > 1. I wonder if it is possible to do it without group by to improve performance? This SQL will be run over a million rows. I'll update the question with this comment as well.

Comment: If you're not going to do a group by then you'll have to look at doing select distinct or something similar. i'd be interested to see which would perform better. As you have the data, could you let me know if you find a better performing way of doing this?

Comment: I tried this on over 3-4 million rows, took a couple of seconds. Haven't compared with the other approaches yet.

Answer (score 0):

How about using HASH.  (very similar to an answer I posted the other day)

```
Declare @Table table (id int,Col1 varchar(25),Col2 varchar(25),Col3 varchar(25))
Insert into @Table values
(1,'A','A2','B3'),
(2,'B','A2','B3'),
(3,'C','A22','B33'),
(4,'D','A22','B33')

Select Distinct Col2,Col3,UniqueID=abs(cast(HashBytes('MD5', Col2+Col3) as int)) 
 From @Table
```

Returns

```
Col2    Col3    UniqueID
A2      B3      768457807
A22     B33     915487006
```

Comment: Thank you. I didn't know of creating these hash values, interesting approach. This will probably require a group by too, right? Also, what are the performance implications of this hashing given we're talking about a million rows worth of data.

Comment: @Achilles  It is an SQL inline function.   I used this when masking account information for 10's of thousands of accounts.   They beauty is that it is consistent and you never have to worry about sequence.  For example, in the sample above, an AA is added tomorrow, that would now be #1 in the sequence.

Comment: @Achilles in my answer above, remove DISTINCT and see what you get

Answer (score 0):

Just another way to solve your problem (**Without Using Distinct or Group By**) by using a Identity column and the SQL Analytics function LAG to get values from the previous row. So this wont work for SQL Server Versions below 2012.

**Performance**: I do not know if this will be faster. If you can describe the dataflow, Table ins/upd frequences and usage pattern maybe we can measure and compare and maybe even come up with other (better) alternatives.

**Assumptions**: Col2+Col3 = Unique in **Output** data table. 
ID column can be converted to a Identity column (or a PK column ) on the source table ( = @Temp_Tbl below ). And the Uniq_ID Column in the Output does not have to be Serial (IF so then just a minor tweak on the Select stmt is necessary)

**How it works** :
The dervied query block X gets the Previous Values for Col2 and Col3 based on the Order of Col2 and Col3 to obtain 2 derived columns Col2_Prev and Col3_Prev.  We then use these columns to eliminated the duplicates by using them in the where clause.

```
DECLARE @Temp_Tbl TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY(1,1) , Col1 VARCHAR(5), Col2 VARCHAR(5),Col3 VARCHAR(5))

INSERT INTO @Temp_Tbl ( Col1 , Col2, Col3 ) VALUES
('A','A2','B3')     ,
('B','A2','B3')     ,
('C','A22','B33')   ,
('D','A22','B33')   ,
('E','A222','B333') ,
('F','A222','B333') ,
('B1','A2','B3')

 SELECT
         X.ID as Uniq_ID
        ,X.Col1 
        ,X.Col2 
        ,X.Col3 
    --  ,X.Col2_Prev  -- Uncomment For Troubleshooting
    --  ,X.Col3_Prev  -- Uncomment For Troubleshooting
 FROM 
         (
            SELECT  A.*     , 
                    Lag(A.Col2, 1, 0) OVER (ORDER BY A.Col2,A.Col3) as  Col2_Prev ,  -- Get Value for Col2 from Previous Row
                    Lag(A.Col3, 1, 0) OVER (ORDER BY A.Col2,A.Col3) as  Col3_Prev    -- Get Value for Col3 from Previous Row
            From @Temp_Tbl A
         ) X
 WHERE X.Col2 <> X.Col2_Prev AND 
       X.Col3 <> X.Col3_Prev
```

**Result:**

```
Uniq_ID Col1 Col2   Col3
1       A    A2     B3
3       C    A22    B33
5       E    A222   B333
```